# Get authentication work with SOAP and PHP

Tags: php, soap, connection

I try to connect to SOAP with php and here is my code:

```
$wsdl = 'http://websiteservicesvplus.mpfrance.fr/WebServicesVPlus.asmx?wsdl';
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
$data = $soap->CheckConnection(
    array(
        'ApiKey'=>'63156585fd3e7a69d6e66c67a92b095b0b8b1478bedffc9137ba9cf8c1dc5088',
        'ApiTokenUserId'=>'5',
        'ApiTokenTypeId'=>'8'
    )
);
var_dump($data);
die;
```

After I run it on the browser, I got this message error only :

> "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. in C:\wamp\www\test\webservices\server1.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\wamp\www\test\webservices\server1.php(23): SoapClient->__call('CheckConnection', Array) #1 C:\wamp\www\test\webservices\server1.php(23): SoapClient->CheckConnection(Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\test\webservices\server1.php on line 23"

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would use a WSDL to php generator to ease the SOAP Web Service consumption (like using the [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator) project),

Second, you're missing the SOAPHeader declared in:

`<wsdl:operation name="CheckConnection">
    <soap12:operation soapAction="http://qpc.ebp.be/CheckConnection" style="document"/>
    <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:CheckConnectionAuthHeader" part="AuthHeader" use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>`.
Once again, using the project references before, it will be defined in the tutorial.php file in order to send it easily.